# Exported small .png image from Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 is Pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, resize, pixelation

I exported a .png image from Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 to use as a logo on my website. It is quite large (1241px x 1346px) and it is slowing the site down dramatically. It needs to be around 100px x 105px, but when I export it from Illustrator in this size it is completely pixelated.

I have resized the artboard, with a 2px border and as far as I can tell I am doing everything I normally do to export a .png image from Illustrator.

I would be most grateful if someone could advise me on this as it driving me to distraction.

Thanks in advance,
nigel

Comment: Are you scaling the image in the web page after you made as small as that? If you scale up a tiny raster image, you will see the pixels! Why don't you use an SVG? Then you could scale it to any size you want.

Answer (score 1):

100 x 105 pixels is tiny. There are not many pixels in the image so any level of detail is going to appear pixelated, especially if you are viewing it at a large magnification. However, if the image in question is going to be very small on the website then it should look fine.

As an example, here is a 100 x 105 pixel screenshot from this page:

[image]

I've scaled it up so that you can see the pixels. It looks very pixelated at this size, but in context (above) it looks fine. Same pixels, just smaller. Hopefully this is the case with your image, but if the image appears pixelated in the context of the final page design then it probably needs to be higher resolution.